# Regex - replace string - no spaces at charAt(0)

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

```
    return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();}).replace(/\s/, '');
```

I just want to prevent any spaces at the beginning of the string (they can be in the substring)

Comment: What about the trim function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's `trim`, as Dani mentioned, but that removes spaces from both ends of the string.  If it *must* be just the start of the string you can do this:

```
'   foo bar'.replace(/^\s+/, ''); // 'foo bar'
```

Answer (score 2):

To remove spaces at the start of a string in JavaScript

```
str.replace(/^\s+/, '')
```